# How can I send URLs from tmux to my browse with urlscan?

Tags: tmux

I would think the following snippet in my tmux.conf would work:

```
bind-key C-u run-shell "tmux capture-pane -Jp | urlscan -d"
```

But all I get with `<prefix> C-u` is:

```
'tmux capture-pane -Jp | urlscan -d' returned 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to tmux manual:

> - run-shell [ -bC] [-d *delay*] [ -t *target-pane*] [*shell-command*]
>   ( alias: `run` )
>
>   Execute *shell-command* using `/bin/sh` or (with `-C`) a tmux command **in the background** without creating a window. [...]

Since `urlscan` requires a tty to work properly it does not work when it is run *in the background*.

I guess this is what you want:

```
bind-key C-u run "tmux popup -E -b double -w 100% -h 100% \
                  sh -c 'tmux capture-pane -Jp | urlscan -d' "
```

---

[image]